# No more room for LISP objects error wxMaxima

Tags: performance, lisp, heap-memory, wxmaxima

I am trying to solve a non-linear equation system with maxima.
I use wxmaxima (17.05.0). The non-linear system is rather long and I am deeply sorry for posting the hole problem, but otherwise I do not think my problem will be clear.
I would like to solve these equations for eleven unkowns (K2 to K11) When I run this after some time the error message "No more room for LISP objects" occurs.
I have no glue how I can give it more cpu or to avoid the error.
I need the symbolic solutions for further calculations.

```
debugmode(true);
gcd : subres;


eq1:mBA*(K10*RABm10 + K11*RABm11 + K12*RABm12 + K7*RABm7 + K8*RABm8 + K9*RABm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RBm2 + K3*RBm3 + K4*RBm4 + K5*RBm5 + K6*RBm6) + 
   mAB*(K10*RABm10 + K11*RABm11 + K12*RABm12 + K7*RABm7 + K8*RABm8 + 
      K9*RABm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RBm10 + K11*M11*RBm11 + K12*M12*RBm12 + K2*M2*RBm2 + 
      K3*M3*RBm3 + K4*M4*RBm4 + K5*M5*RBm5 + K6*M6*RBm6 + K7*M7*RBm7 + 
      K8*M8*RBm8 + K9*M9*RBm9) =
  mBA*(K10*RABm10 + K11*RABm11 + K12*RABm12 + K7*RABm7 + K8*RABm8 + 
      K9*RABm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RBm10 + K11*RBm11 + K12*RBm12 + K7*RBm7 + K8*RBm8 + K9*RBm9) + 
   mAB*(K10*RABm10 + K11*RABm11 + K12*RABm12 + K7*RABm7 + K8*RABm8 + 
      K9*RABm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RBm10 + K11*M11*RBm11 + K12*M12*RBm12 + 
      K2*M2*RBm2 + K3*M3*RBm3 + K4*M4*RBm4 + K5*M5*RBm5 + K6*M6*RBm6 + 
      K7*M7*RBm7 + K8*M8*RBm8 + K9*M9*RBm9)$

eq2:mCA*(K10*RACm10 + K11*RACm11 + K12*RACm12 + K7*RACm7 + K8*RACm8 + K9*RACm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RCm2 + K3*RCm3 + K4*RCm4 + K5*RCm5 + K6*RCm6) + 
   mAC*(K10*RACm10 + K11*RACm11 + K12*RACm12 + K7*RACm7 + K8*RACm8 + 
      K9*RACm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RCm10 + K11*M11*RCm11 + K12*M12*RCm12 + K2*M2*RCm2 + 
      K3*M3*RCm3 + K4*M4*RCm4 + K5*M5*RCm5 + K6*M6*RCm6 + K7*M7*RCm7 + 
      K8*M8*RCm8 + K9*M9*RCm9) =
  mCA*(K10*RACm10 + K11*RACm11 + K12*RACm12 + K7*RACm7 + K8*RACm8 + 
      K9*RACm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RCm10 + K11*RCm11 + K12*RCm12 + K7*RCm7 + K8*RCm8 + K9*RCm9) + 
   mAC*(K10*RACm10 + K11*RACm11 + K12*RACm12 + K7*RACm7 + K8*RACm8 + 
      K9*RACm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RCm10 + K11*M11*RCm11 + K12*M12*RCm12 + 
      K2*M2*RCm2 + K3*M3*RCm3 + K4*M4*RCm4 + K5*M5*RCm5 + K6*M6*RCm6 + 
      K7*M7*RCm7 + K8*M8*RCm8 + K9*M9*RCm9)$

eq3:mDA*(K10*RADm10 + K11*RADm11 + K12*RADm12 + K7*RADm7 + K8*RADm8 + K9*RADm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RDm2 + K3*RDm3 + K4*RDm4 + K5*RDm5 + K6*RDm6) + 
   mAD*(K10*RADm10 + K11*RADm11 + K12*RADm12 + K7*RADm7 + K8*RADm8 + 
      K9*RADm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RDm10 + K11*M11*RDm11 + K12*M12*RDm12 + K2*M2*RDm2 + 
      K3*M3*RDm3 + K4*M4*RDm4 + K5*M5*RDm5 + K6*M6*RDm6 + K7*M7*RDm7 + 
      K8*M8*RDm8 + K9*M9*RDm9) =
  mDA*(K10*RADm10 + K11*RADm11 + K12*RADm12 + K7*RADm7 + K8*RADm8 + 
      K9*RADm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RDm10 + K11*RDm11 + K12*RDm12 + K7*RDm7 + K8*RDm8 + K9*RDm9) + 
   mAD*(K10*RADm10 + K11*RADm11 + K12*RADm12 + K7*RADm7 + K8*RADm8 + 
      K9*RADm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RDm10 + K11*M11*RDm11 + K12*M12*RDm12 + 
      K2*M2*RDm2 + K3*M3*RDm3 + K4*M4*RDm4 + K5*M5*RDm5 + K6*M6*RDm6 + 
      K7*M7*RDm7 + K8*M8*RDm8 + K9*M9*RDm9)$

eq4:mEA*(K10*RAEm10 + K11*RAEm11 + K12*RAEm12 + K7*RAEm7 + K8*RAEm8 + K9*RAEm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*REm2 + K3*REm3 + K4*REm4 + K5*REm5 + K6*REm6) + 
   mAE*(K10*RAEm10 + K11*RAEm11 + K12*RAEm12 + K7*RAEm7 + K8*RAEm8 + 
      K9*RAEm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*REm10 + K11*M11*REm11 + K12*M12*REm12 + K2*M2*REm2 + 
      K3*M3*REm3 + K4*M4*REm4 + K5*M5*REm5 + K6*M6*REm6 + K7*M7*REm7 + 
      K8*M8*REm8 + K9*M9*REm9) =
  mEA*(K10*RAEm10 + K11*RAEm11 + K12*RAEm12 + K7*RAEm7 + K8*RAEm8 + 
      K9*RAEm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*REm10 + K11*REm11 + K12*REm12 + K7*REm7 + K8*REm8 + K9*REm9) + 
   mAE*(K10*RAEm10 + K11*RAEm11 + K12*RAEm12 + K7*RAEm7 + K8*RAEm8 + 
      K9*RAEm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*REm10 + K11*M11*REm11 + K12*M12*REm12 + 
      K2*M2*REm2 + K3*M3*REm3 + K4*M4*REm4 + K5*M5*REm5 + K6*M6*REm6 + 
      K7*M7*REm7 + K8*M8*REm8 + K9*M9*REm9)$

eq5:mFA*(K10*RAFm10 + K11*RAFm11 + K12*RAFm12 + K7*RAFm7 + K8*RAFm8 + K9*RAFm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RFm2 + K3*RFm3 + K4*RFm4 + K5*RFm5 + K6*RFm6) + 
   mAF*(K10*RAFm10 + K11*RAFm11 + K12*RAFm12 + K7*RAFm7 + K8*RAFm8 + 
      K9*RAFm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RFm10 + K11*M11*RFm11 + K12*M12*RFm12 + K2*M2*RFm2 + 
      K3*M3*RFm3 + K4*M4*RFm4 + K5*M5*RFm5 + K6*M6*RFm6 + K7*M7*RFm7 + 
      K8*M8*RFm8 + K9*M9*RFm9) =
  mFA*(K10*RAFm10 + K11*RAFm11 + K12*RAFm12 + K7*RAFm7 + K8*RAFm8 + 
      K9*RAFm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RFm10 + K11*RFm11 + K12*RFm12 + K7*RFm7 + K8*RFm8 + K9*RFm9) + 
   mAF*(K10*RAFm10 + K11*RAFm11 + K12*RAFm12 + K7*RAFm7 + K8*RAFm8 + 
      K9*RAFm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RFm10 + K11*M11*RFm11 + K12*M12*RFm12 + 
      K2*M2*RFm2 + K3*M3*RFm3 + K4*M4*RFm4 + K5*M5*RFm5 + K6*M6*RFm6 + 
      K7*M7*RFm7 + K8*M8*RFm8 + K9*M9*RFm9)$

eq6:mGA*(K10*RAGm10 + K11*RAGm11 + K12*RAGm12 + K7*RAGm7 + K8*RAGm8 + K9*RAGm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RGm2 + K3*RGm3 + K4*RGm4 + K5*RGm5 + K6*RGm6) + 
   mAG*(K10*RAGm10 + K11*RAGm11 + K12*RAGm12 + K7*RAGm7 + K8*RAGm8 + 
      K9*RAGm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RGm10 + K11*M11*RGm11 + K12*M12*RGm12 + K2*M2*RGm2 + 
      K3*M3*RGm3 + K4*M4*RGm4 + K5*M5*RGm5 + K6*M6*RGm6 + K7*M7*RGm7 + 
      K8*M8*RGm8 + K9*M9*RGm9) =
  mGA*(K10*RAGm10 + K11*RAGm11 + K12*RAGm12 + K7*RAGm7 + K8*RAGm8 + 
      K9*RAGm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RGm10 + K11*RGm11 + K12*RGm12 + K7*RGm7 + K8*RGm8 + K9*RGm9) + 
   mAG*(K10*RAGm10 + K11*RAGm11 + K12*RAGm12 + K7*RAGm7 + K8*RAGm8 + 
      K9*RAGm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RGm10 + K11*M11*RGm11 + K12*M12*RGm12 + 
      K2*M2*RGm2 + K3*M3*RGm3 + K4*M4*RGm4 + K5*M5*RGm5 + K6*M6*RGm6 + 
      K7*M7*RGm7 + K8*M8*RGm8 + K9*M9*RGm9)$

eq7:mHA*(K10*RAHm10 + K11*RAHm11 + K12*RAHm12 + K7*RAHm7 + K8*RAHm8 + K9*RAHm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RHm2 + K3*RHm3 + K4*RHm4 + K5*RHm5 + K6*RHm6) + 
   mAH*(K10*RAHm10 + K11*RAHm11 + K12*RAHm12 + K7*RAHm7 + K8*RAHm8 + 
      K9*RAHm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RHm10 + K11*M11*RHm11 + K12*M12*RHm12 + K2*M2*RHm2 + 
      K3*M3*RHm3 + K4*M4*RHm4 + K5*M5*RHm5 + K6*M6*RHm6 + K7*M7*RHm7 + 
      K8*M8*RHm8 + K9*M9*RHm9) =
  mHA*(K10*RAHm10 + K11*RAHm11 + K12*RAHm12 + K7*RAHm7 + K8*RAHm8 + 
      K9*RAHm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RHm10 + K11*RHm11 + K12*RHm12 + K7*RHm7 + K8*RHm8 + K9*RHm9) + 
   mAH*(K10*RAHm10 + K11*RAHm11 + K12*RAHm12 + K7*RAHm7 + K8*RAHm8 + 
      K9*RAHm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RHm10 + K11*M11*RHm11 + K12*M12*RHm12 + 
      K2*M2*RHm2 + K3*M3*RHm3 + K4*M4*RHm4 + K5*M5*RHm5 + K6*M6*RHm6 + 
      K7*M7*RHm7 + K8*M8*RHm8 + K9*M9*RHm9)$

eq8:mIA*(K10*RAIm10 + K11*RAIm11 + K12*RAIm12 + K7*RAIm7 + K8*RAIm8 + K9*RAIm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RIm2 + K3*RIm3 + K4*RIm4 + K5*RIm5 + K6*RIm6) + 
   mAI*(K10*RAIm10 + K11*RAIm11 + K12*RAIm12 + K7*RAIm7 + K8*RAIm8 + 
      K9*RAIm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RIm10 + K11*M11*RIm11 + K12*M12*RIm12 + K2*M2*RIm2 + 
      K3*M3*RIm3 + K4*M4*RIm4 + K5*M5*RIm5 + K6*M6*RIm6 + K7*M7*RIm7 + 
      K8*M8*RIm8 + K9*M9*RIm9) =
  mIA*(K10*RAIm10 + K11*RAIm11 + K12*RAIm12 + K7*RAIm7 + K8*RAIm8 + 
      K9*RAIm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RIm10 + K11*RIm11 + K12*RIm12 + K7*RIm7 + K8*RIm8 + K9*RIm9) + 
   mAI*(K10*RAIm10 + K11*RAIm11 + K12*RAIm12 + K7*RAIm7 + K8*RAIm8 + 
      K9*RAIm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RIm10 + K11*M11*RIm11 + K12*M12*RIm12 + 
      K2*M2*RIm2 + K3*M3*RIm3 + K4*M4*RIm4 + K5*M5*RIm5 + K6*M6*RIm6 + 
      K7*M7*RIm7 + K8*M8*RIm8 + K9*M9*RIm9)$

eq9:mJA*(K10*RAJm10 + K11*RAJm11 + K12*RAJm12 + K7*RAJm7 + K8*RAJm8 + K9*RAJm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RJm2 + K3*RJm3 + K4*RJm4 + K5*RJm5 + K6*RJm6) + 
   mAJ*(K10*RAJm10 + K11*RAJm11 + K12*RAJm12 + K7*RAJm7 + K8*RAJm8 + 
      K9*RAJm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RJm10 + K11*M11*RJm11 + K12*M12*RJm12 + K2*M2*RJm2 + 
      K3*M3*RJm3 + K4*M4*RJm4 + K5*M5*RJm5 + K6*M6*RJm6 + K7*M7*RJm7 + 
      K8*M8*RJm8 + K9*M9*RJm9) =
  mJA*(K10*RAJm10 + K11*RAJm11 + K12*RAJm12 + K7*RAJm7 + K8*RAJm8 + 
      K9*RAJm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RJm10 + K11*RJm11 + K12*RJm12 + K7*RJm7 + K8*RJm8 + K9*RJm9) + 
   mAJ*(K10*RAJm10 + K11*RAJm11 + K12*RAJm12 + K7*RAJm7 + K8*RAJm8 + 
      K9*RAJm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RJm10 + K11*M11*RJm11 + K12*M12*RJm12 + 
      K2*M2*RJm2 + K3*M3*RJm3 + K4*M4*RJm4 + K5*M5*RJm5 + K6*M6*RJm6 + 
      K7*M7*RJm7 + K8*M8*RJm8 + K9*M9*RJm9)$

eq10:mKA*(K10*RAKm10 + K11*RAKm11 + K12*RAKm12 + K7*RAKm7 + K8*RAKm8 + K9*RAKm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RKm2 + K3*RKm3 + K4*RKm4 + K5*RKm5 + K6*RKm6) + 
   mAK*(K10*RAKm10 + K11*RAKm11 + K12*RAKm12 + K7*RAKm7 + K8*RAKm8 + 
      K9*RAKm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RKm10 + K11*M11*RKm11 + K12*M12*RKm12 + K2*M2*RKm2 + 
      K3*M3*RKm3 + K4*M4*RKm4 + K5*M5*RKm5 + K6*M6*RKm6 + K7*M7*RKm7 + 
      K8*M8*RKm8 + K9*M9*RKm9) =
  mKA*(K10*RAKm10 + K11*RAKm11 + K12*RAKm12 + K7*RAKm7 + K8*RAKm8 + 
      K9*RAKm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RKm10 + K11*RKm11 + K12*RKm12 + K7*RKm7 + K8*RKm8 + K9*RKm9) + 
   mAK*(K10*RAKm10 + K11*RAKm11 + K12*RAKm12 + K7*RAKm7 + K8*RAKm8 + 
      K9*RAKm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RKm10 + K11*M11*RKm11 + K12*M12*RKm12 + 
      K2*M2*RKm2 + K3*M3*RKm3 + K4*M4*RKm4 + K5*M5*RKm5 + K6*M6*RKm6 + 
      K7*M7*RKm7 + K8*M8*RKm8 + K9*M9*RKm9)$

eq11:mLA*(K10*RALm10 + K11*RALm11 + K12*RALm12 + K7*RALm7 + K8*RALm8 + K9*RALm9)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + K2*M2*RAm2 + 
      K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + K7*M7*RAm7 + 
      K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (1 + K2*RLm2 + K3*RLm3 + K4*RLm4 + K5*RLm5 + K6*RLm6) + 
   mAL*(K10*RALm10 + K11*RALm11 + K12*RALm12 + K7*RALm7 + K8*RALm8 + 
      K9*RALm9)*(1 + K2*RAm2 + K3*RAm3 + K4*RAm4 + K5*RAm5 + K6*RAm6)*
    (M1 + K10*M10*RLm10 + K11*M11*RLm11 + K12*M12*RLm12 + K2*M2*RLm2 + 
      K3*M3*RLm3 + K4*M4*RLm4 + K5*M5*RLm5 + K6*M6*RLm6 + K7*M7*RLm7 + 
      K8*M8*RLm8 + K9*M9*RLm9) =
  mLA*(K10*RALm10 + K11*RALm11 + K12*RALm12 + K7*RALm7 + K8*RALm8 + 
      K9*RALm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RAm10 + K11*M11*RAm11 + K12*M12*RAm12 + 
      K2*M2*RAm2 + K3*M3*RAm3 + K4*M4*RAm4 + K5*M5*RAm5 + K6*M6*RAm6 + 
      K7*M7*RAm7 + K8*M8*RAm8 + K9*M9*RAm9)*
    (K10*RLm10 + K11*RLm11 + K12*RLm12 + K7*RLm7 + K8*RLm8 + K9*RLm9) + 
   mAL*(K10*RALm10 + K11*RALm11 + K12*RALm12 + K7*RALm7 + K8*RALm8 + 
      K9*RALm9)*(K10*RAm10 + K11*RAm11 + K12*RAm12 + K7*RAm7 + K8*RAm8 + 
      K9*RAm9)*(M1 + K10*M10*RLm10 + K11*M11*RLm11 + K12*M12*RLm12 + 
      K2*M2*RLm2 + K3*M3*RLm3 + K4*M4*RLm4 + K5*M5*RLm5 + K6*M6*RLm6 + 
      K7*M7*RLm7 + K8*M8*RLm8 + K9*M9*RLm9)$


sol:solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11],[K2,K3,K4,K5,K6,K7,K8,K9,K10,K11])$
```

Here are the missing infos about my system.

wxMaxima version: 17.05.0

Maxima version: 5.40.0

Maxima build date: 2017-06-01 18:54:32

Host type: x86_64-w64-mingw32

System type: 
gcc -mno-cygwin -g -O2 -W -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-format-nonliteral -O2 -fexpensive-optimizations -falign-functions=4 -D_WIN32 -DENABLE_UNICODE -I/usr/local/include -DDYNAMIC_FFI -I. -L/usr/local/lib  -lintl /usr/local/lib/libreadline.dll.a -L/usr/local/lib -ltermcap /usr/local/lib/libavcall.a /usr/local/lib/libcallback.a -luser32 -lws2_32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -liconv -L/usr/local/lib -lsigsegv libgnu_cl.a 
SAFETY=0 HEAPCODES STANDARD_HEAPCODES GENERATIONAL_GC SPVW_BLOCKS SPVW_MIXED TRIVIALMAP_MEMORY
libsigsegv 2.8
libiconv 1.13
libreadline 6.0 GNU C 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) PC/386

Lisp implementation type: CLISP

Lisp implementation version: 2.49 (2010-07-07) (built on toshiba [192.168.43.206])

[image]

Comment: Which Common Lisp are you using as backend? FYI, you can check it by running `:lisp (lisp-implementation-type)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like heap exhaustion. Using the `:lisp` directive from my comment above, you can investigate the current heap size in the underlying Lisp. This is implementation-specific, but assuming you're running on SBCL, the following would retrieve the heap size:

```
:lisp (cl-user::dynamic-space-size)
```

Now, Maxima recognizes an environment variable `MAXIMA_LISP_OPTIONS`, which is just a list of command line parameters passed to Lisp. In SBCL there's a parameter `--dynamic-space-size`, which specifies the heap size in megabytes. So by running Maxima as follows:

```
MAXIMA_LISP_OPTIONS="--dynamic-space-size 10000" maxima
```

you should run the underlying SBCL with 10 GB of heap space, which you can verify as above. This approach would have to be appropriately modified for other Lisp implementations. Let me know if this allows your calculations to run to completion.

Comment: Okay, I will try this, but as I am a newbie I don't know how to add this in a wxmaxima file. Just adding this line?
MAXIMA_LISP_OPTIONS="--dynamic-space-size 10000" maxima

Comment: This is a shell environment variable. You either prepend it to your invocation of Maxima (actually, this would also work with `wxmaxima`) in your shell, or, if you run `wxMaxima` from a graphical launcher, you should export the above variable in your shell config file. Assuming you're running Bash, this would mean adding `export MAXIMA_LISP_OPTIONS="--dynamic-space-size 10000"` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Okay, is there no way of giving it directly to wxmaxima? To be honest I do not  know where the basgrc file is, but i knwo that with wxmaxima one can give maxima additional parameters. It is in the Settings, I have added a Picture were I have added your command but it still does not work and I get the error,

Comment: Ok, I see you misunderstood what the line in my answer stands for. What that line meant was environment variable setup for the invocation of `maxima` (hence the `maxima` at the end). Since you're on Windows, that would be a bit different. In fact, your screenshot reveals the syntax for passing parameters to Lisp. But your system info also reveals that your Maxima is running on Clisp. Honestly, I don't know how to increase the heap size in Clisp. I think your best bet would be to install SBCL Maxima and apply the above. [Here's](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/windows-install.html) how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for that tip! Now I can increase the heap size but only up to 2GB, although I have at least 8 GB. Maybe you have also a solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean to say that any value you specify above 2GB is limited to 2GB? Have you verified it using the above invocation?

Comment: I have found a different solution for my problem.

Comment: Please elaborate. And/or post that as an answer to your question for others to see.

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to response. I changed the maxima.bat file.
There is a line were yu can alter the default value of the dynamic-space-size.
I could change it to 8GB, what is the maximum I can offer. Nethertheless, it did not help, I assume my input is just to complex and I need to reduce it somehow.

Comment: Yes. Well, I ran your computation on a 10 GB heap size and also had to terminate it as it wouldn't come to an end.

Comment: Mhmm okay, but I assume you do not have a tip for reducing the computating time/effort.

Comment: OK, now this is a completely different question :). Actually, I haven't given much thought to the mathematical aspect of your problem. I'll try to think of something. But this might merit a separate question. You might also want to mark an answer to this one - either yours, which better matches your actual problem with Maxima on Windows, or mine, which identified the root problem as you originally specified it. Up to you.

Comment: First off, I tried using `algsys` instead  of `solve`, based on some comments in the documentation, but it was also taking forever. No luck here.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a line in the maxima.bat file.
There you can find some thing like

```
if exist "%maxima_prefix%/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" (

    if "%lisp_options%"=="" set lisp_options=--dynamic-space-size^ 200

)
```

I have changed the 200 MB to 8000 MB, this help me to increase the heap size but still I was not able to solve my system of non-linear equations.